# How to automatically change user folders location?

Tags: active-directory, user-profile

In a Windows Server 2008 R2 Active Directory how can I make sure that each user open login have their `Desktop`, `Documents`, `Links`, `Pictures`, etc folders set to a shared private folder?

For example, instead of the default `C:\Users\<username>\Documents` I would like that this would be set automatically to `Z:\Documents`.

Back in the old days of me being Admin, I recall it's some script set up in the user profile, but I can't remember that well and by using my poor English skills I can't track what to search for this issue.

All users either have Windows 7 Professional or Windows 8 Professional.

Answer (score 1):

Folder Redirection in Group Policy is the answer to your prayers and is designed for *exactly* this - however, you should use full UNC paths (\\SERVER01\HomeFolders$) rather than mapped drivers.

Here is the place to start reading:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778976(v=ws.10).aspx